# End Point in Retrofit URL

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit

in my application using Retrofit. I had declared interface, But I am not sure how to use Endpoint in this url.

my URL is:`http://javatechig.com/api/get_category_posts/?dev=1&slug=android`

Now my question is how to add endpoint for this url. my interface is like:

```
public interface Api {

@GET("/WHAT COMES HERE")
void getItem(WHAT_COMES HERE,
                Callback<FeedItem> callback);

}
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated Thanks in advance

Comment: `END_POINT="http://javatechig.com/api/get_category_posts/"` and `@GET("?dev=1&slug=android")` // Just an example. And use it like this:`Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(END_POINT);`

Comment: Glad to help. Want me to post this as an answer to help others with the same problem?

Comment: What about the second WHAT_COMES_HERE in the parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ENDPOINT is the part of the URL which will be the same for all services URLs (in most cases). Eg: suppose facebook is giving a service, then its ENDPOINT is going to be like "http://www.facebook.com/" and then you can add any request POST/GEt by add "user_name OR page_name" //Just an example.

So what you need to do to set the end point is something like:

`END_POINT="http://javatechig.com/api/get_category_posts/";`

and then use it like:

```
Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(END_POINT);
...
...
@GET("?dev=1&slug=android")
```

Hope it helps.